# XSL Transformation help

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I currently have the following XML file:

```
<Regions>
  <Region>
     <Code>AU</Code>
     <Name>Austria</Name>
  </Region>
</Regions>
<Channels>
    <Channel>
      <Code>00</Code>
      <Name>Im a channel</Name>
    </Channel>
    ...
</Channels>
<Programs>
   <Program>
      <Code>00</Code>
      <Name>Program</Name>          
   </Program>
</Programs>
```

I would only like to keep the **Channels** path so that the output would look like this using an XSLT:

```
<Channels>
    <Channel>
      <Code>00</Code>
      <Name>Im a channel</Name>
    </Channel>
    ...
</Channels>
```

Comment: Could you give us an example of how you want the output to look like?

Comment: What “path“ are you talking about?

Comment: Elaborated a bit more, sorry didn't have much information in there.

Comment: Are you asking to keep the `<Channels>` tag and its contents while deleting the other tags?

Comment: You realize the XML is not valid, right? It has multiple top-level tags (or is there an enclosing tag you've omitted?)

Comment: Jim: Yep I would like to only keep the Channels tag. I just fixed the top level tags.

Comment: @schone: No, you *didn't* fix the problem. Any well-formed XML document by definition must have only one top element.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution that is based on the most fundamental XSLT design pattern -- using and overriding the identity rule. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/t/*[not(self::Channels)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document (fixed to be made well-formed):**

```
<t>
    <Regions>
        <Region>
            <Code>AU</Code>
            <Name>Austria</Name>
        </Region>
    </Regions>
    <Channels>
        <Channel>
            <Code>00</Code>
            <Name>Im a channel</Name>
        </Channel>    
    </Channels>
    <Programs>
        <Program>
            <Code>00</Code>
            <Name>Program</Name>
        </Program>
    </Programs>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<Channels>
   <Channel>
      <Code>00</Code>
      <Name>Im a channel</Name>
   </Channel>
</Channels>
```

**Explanation**:

Use of the *identity rule*, overriden for the top element (pass-through) and for any non-`Channels` children of the top element (delete).